# PyEnv cannot build Python 3.9.4 on MacOSX Monterey 12.4, Apple Silicon M1

Tags: python, gcc, apple-m1, pyenv, macos-monterey

Context:

- Homebrew (updated)
- Homebrew GCC 12.2.0
- Pyenv 2.3.5
- MacOSX Monterey 12.4, Apple Silicon M1
- Tried all suggestions I could find online, about installing zlib, bzip, etc. All seems to be in order, as far as I can tell (but I might be wrong, of course).

This is how it fails:

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [Objects/floatobject.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ./Include/pythread.h:128,
                 from ./Include/Python.h:136,
                 from Objects/methodobject.c:4:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:328:6: warning: this use of "defined" may not be portable [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
  328 | #if !_PTHREAD_SWIFT_IMPORTER_NULLABILITY_COMPAT
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:328:6: warning: this use of "defined" may not be portable [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:537:6: warning: this use of "defined" may not be portable [-Wexpansion-to-defined]
  537 | #if !_PTHREAD_SWIFT_IMPORTER_NULLABILITY_COMPAT
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/pthread.h:537:6: warning: this use of "defined" may not be portable [-Wexpansion-to-defined]

BUILD FAILED (OS X 12.4 using python-build 20180424)
```

Here's the [complete output of the pyenv install](https://gist.github.com/stefanomasini/c87a8b3ab2e2c8a2820781da3a742ce9) command.

Any idea about what could be going wrong in my system?
How can I debug further? Where should I look?